# Generating TestResult with nunit-console failing

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, specflow, gherkin

According to the SpecFlow website, I can generate the TestResult by executing the following statement:

```
nunit3-console.exe --labels=All --out=TestResult.txt "--result=TestResult.xml;format=nunit2" bin\Debug\BookShop.AcceptanceTests.dll
```

I've adapted this statement to the following:

```
nunit3-console.exe --labels=All --out=C:\temp\TestResult.txt "--result=C:\temp\TestResult.xml;format=nunit2" C:\Projects\DataService.IntegrationTests\bin\Debug\DataService.IntegrationTests.dll
```

Unfortunately, I get the following errors:

> Errors, Failures and Warnings
>
> 1) Invalid : C:\Projects\DataService.IntegrationTests\bin\Debug\DataService.IntegrationTests.dll
>   No suitable tests found in 'C:\Projects\DataService.IntegrationTests\bin\Debug.DataService.IntegrationTests.dll'.
>   Either assembly contains no tests or proper test driver has not been found.

The `.feature` file are available in this assembly...

What could be the problem here?

An assumption of mine is, that we're using `Specflow.MsTest`...
Is there a way to generate the `TestResult.xml` by using `MsTest`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you have configured as your unitTestProvider in your app.config?

Comment: I have configured MSTest

Comment: Ok, but why do you then execute the tests via NUnit? You have to use vstest.console.exe for MsTest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NUnit3-console can only run NUnit tests. (Well technically, it can run any tests for which a driver is provided, but it amounts to the same thing.)

If you want to create NUnit output, then use both the NUnit framework and the NUnit console runner. MsTest doesn't do NUnit output.

Answer (score 0):

In app.condig I don't have any unitTestProvider

```
  <specFlow>
    <stepAssemblies>
      <stepAssembly assembly="otherProject" />
    </stepAssemblies>
    <runtime detectAmbiguousMatches="true" stopAtFirstError="false" missingOrPendingStepsOutcome="Inconclusive" />
    <trace traceSuccessfulSteps="true" traceTimings="false" minTracedDuration="0:0:0.1" />
    <!-- For additional details on SpecFlow configuration options see http://go.specflow.org/doc-config -->
  </specFlow>
```